# Gstreamer pipeline to play Mp3 file on windows

Tags: gstreamer

I have installed Gstreamer OSS build on windows and i am able to play test audio on my system.
Can some share with me a Gstreamer pipeline to play mp3 file in windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the canonical way to play all supported media:

```
gst-launch playbin2 uri=[the media to play]
```

Comment: Ya , i know about this, i want a pipeline with various elements linked togather.

Comment: Why? If for curiosity, check what elements gstreamer has picked (gst-launch -v).